# OctoberCMS media manager set max file upload limit

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I developed a website in OctoberCMS. How to set max size image upload limit or generate different image version(like a thumb, medium, large image etc.) in media manager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage the code yourself I would suggest to use media manager events to manipulate files uploaded via media manager

https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/mediamanager#events

or you can use this plugin, not sure if it will cover all your needs as more info needed

https://octobercms.com/plugin/toughdeveloper-imageresizer